# Android - Voice recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am looking for a voice recognition library for Android. I only need it to understand "Yes/No" answers ( in different languages - like English, German, French ).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about V-R libraries because the Play Store max App size is 50megs and those voice packages are about 15 to 20 megs each so it will impossible to include multiple languages directly into the App.

There may be an online service to use but you need to search the net for that.

What most people use is the inbuilt Android voice recognition Intent. For different languages should be ok for the ones you want as they are included. However i'm not sure if for example in France when you buy a phone or a tablet the default V-R language will be French and not English, therefore the user will need to go into Language settings and Download the French V-R package.

To start V-R in Android you do

```
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

       private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
        }

//To get the Voice data back as Text string

   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //pull all of the matches
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            String topResult = matches.get(0);

}};
```

The `String topResult` is the speech in text

Comment: Geia sou Taso. Thanks for the info. I think I have the space to add 10-20MBs in my app (we do not have an apk size issue) so I will search for such libs.

Doesn't the "intent" solution mean that the user will be sent to an external application and then return back? I want everything to happen within my application.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Panos - Yiasou file. no what im saying is Per language it will be around 10-20megs, so you maybe able to fit 2 languages only. The inbuilt Android voice recognition intent just opens a small white box on-top of the App, simmilar to this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/821839/2.2.jpg but you can get rid of the box and have a customized one.