# (Android Studio Speech Recognizer) I'm getting error 9 (insufficient Privileges) even though I have given it RECORD_AUDIO and INTERNET

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, nsspeechrecognizer

```
package blessupboys.speechtest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;



public class VoiceRecognitionTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    private TextView mText;
    private SpeechRecognizer sr;
    private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognition_test);
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
    }

    class listener implements RecognitionListener
    {
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
        }
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
        }
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
        }
        public void onEndOfSpeech()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
        }
        public void onError(int error)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
            mText.setText("error " + error);
        }
        public void onResults(Bundle results)
        {
            String str = new String();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
            ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                str += data.get(i);
            }
            mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));
        }
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
        }
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
        }
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);
            sr.startListening(intent);
            Log.i("111111","11111111");
        }
    }
}
```

And My Android Manifest File looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="blessupboys.speechtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VoiceRecognitionTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_voice_recognition_test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

My logs show that it stops because of error 9 generated in the onError() function.

```
01-19 20:04:57.776 18480-18480/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-19 20:04:57.925 18480-18480/blessupboys.speechtest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/blessupboys.speechtest-2/lib/x86
01-19 20:04:58.341 18480-18515/blessupboys.speechtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-19 20:04:58.443 18480-18515/blessupboys.speechtest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-19 20:04:58.497 18480-18515/blessupboys.speechtest W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-19 20:04:58.497 18480-18515/blessupboys.speechtest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79f260, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-19 20:04:59.033 18480-18480/blessupboys.speechtest I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-19 20:10:09.965 18480-18480/blessupboys.speechtest I/111111: 11111111
01-19 20:10:10.049 18480-18480/blessupboys.speechtest D/MyStt3Activity: error 9
```

I am trying to run this sample program to try to get familiar with the Speech Recognizer software..

Could this be an issue being caused by the fact that I'm running it on android studio rather than a real device? I am pretty stuck on this.

Comment: Are you running on an Android 6.0 (API 23) device? Do you have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23?

Comment: i dont think you need any permissions as the actual VR intent has them anyway. Try the voice recorder App in the emulator. Does that work or crash?? if it crashes then its a problem with the internal mic (may need to plug one in) or VR does not work in the emulator.

Comment: Yes I'm using a API23 device (Nexus)

Comment: just tested in emulator with Marshmallow (with Google APIs) image and Speech Recognition works  -- try my Speech recognition code that im using here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960336/android-voice-recognition/32961426#32961426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a problem with it not being supported on emulators. It works on a physical device.

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone comes to this question and none of the other answers help, you might want to try requesting permissions using the following code:

```
private void requestRecordAudioPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

        // If the user previously denied this permission then show a message explaining why
        // this permission is needed
        if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{requiredPermission}, 101);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also make sure you check your apps permissions on the device....

Answer (score 7):

Error 9 `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS` is also thrown when google does not have record_audio permission.

Check the Settings -> Apps -> Google -> Permissions -> Microphone

Recent versions of Android require that for permissions
like RECORD_AUDIO which is considered a PERMISSION_DANGEROUS that not only does the permission have to be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml:

but at run time the user has to grant the permission using 'requestPermission' (as mentioned in Marky's answer)

Comment: Thanks.  This Solved my problem.  Is there any way to check this permission or request on behalf of it?

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that if you are "just a physical device" and you still get the same error, that is most probably is because if the target SDK in the gradle file. you see in later versions they have changed the level of permission to dangers, so by downgrading it, then you it will work.

"I am not an expert in this, but this worked from me fine"

Answer (score -1):

try these links for references to your [project](https://github.com/katchsvartanian/voiceRecognition) also check all android manifest permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) and here is a sample [project](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-speech-recognition-example.html)

hope these hints help to solve your problem!

Comment: I've already looked through all of these. This doesn't help get me any further than what I already knew